# Wildfly CLI XA-Datasource missing property

Tags: database, command-line-interface, wildfly, datasource

I have searched in the official Wildfly 10 documentation and searched the net but strangely I didn't find the solution to my problem. When I run the CLI and try to configure an XA-Datasource I can't configure the property **xa-datasource-property**.

These are the commands I have tried:

```
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestDataSource/:add(driver-name=XA-Oracle,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/testDS,background-validation=false,enlistment-trace=false,flush-strategy=FailingConnectionOnly,max-pool-size=20,min-pool-size=10,no-recovery=false,password=TEST,pool-prefill=true,query-timeout=10,same-rm-override=false,statistics-enabled=true,track-statements=NOWARN,url-property=jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST:orcl,user-name=USERNAME,validate-on-match=false,enabled=true,allow-multiple-users=false,xa-datasource-properties={"URL"=>{"value"=>"jdbc:oracle:thin"}})
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestDataSource/:add(driver-name=XA-Oracle,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/testDS,background-validation=false,enlistment-trace=false,flush-strategy=FailingConnectionOnly,max-pool-size=20,min-pool-size=10,no-recovery=false,password=TEST,pool-prefill=true,query-timeout=10,same-rm-override=false,statistics-enabled=true,track-statements=NOWARN,url-property=jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST:orcl,user-name=USERNAME,validate-on-match=false,enabled=true,allow-multiple-users=false,xa-datasource-properties={"name"=>"URL","value"=>"jdbc:oracle:thin"})
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestDataSource/:add(driver-name=XA-Oracle,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/testDS,background-validation=false,enlistment-trace=false,flush-strategy=FailingConnectionOnly,max-pool-size=20,min-pool-size=10,no-recovery=false,password=TEST,pool-prefill=true,query-timeout=10,same-rm-override=false,statistics-enabled=true,track-statements=NOWARN,url-property=jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST:orcl,user-name=USERNAME,validate-on-match=false,enabled=true,allow-multiple-users=false,xa-datasource-property={"name"=>"URL","value"=>"jdbc:oracle:thin"})
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestDataSource/:add(driver-name=XA-Oracle,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/testDS,background-validation=false,enlistment-trace=false,flush-strategy=FailingConnectionOnly,max-pool-size=20,min-pool-size=10,no-recovery=false,password=TEST,pool-prefill=true,query-timeout=10,same-rm-override=false,statistics-enabled=true,track-statements=NOWARN,url-property=jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST:orcl,user-name=USERNAME,validate-on-match=false,enabled=true,allow-multiple-users=false,xa-datasource-property={"URL"=>{"value"=>"jdbc:oracle:thin"}})
```

No matter which type of configuration I try it will tell me the **property** **xa-datasource-properties** or **xa-datasource-property** is **unknown**. When using TAB to get code completion it will offer my a lot of properties but the required one is not to be found.[image: CLI code completion]

Additionally if I leave it out it will say:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0069: At least one xa-datasource-property is required for an xa-datasource",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some weird reason it was only possible using a different syntax which looks like this:

```
xa-data-source add --name=Test --allow-multiple-users=false --connectable=true --driver-name=XA-Oracle --enabled=true --interleaving=false --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/test --max-pool-size=20 --min-pool-size=10 --no-tx-separate-pool=false --pad-xid=false --password=PASSWORD --pool-prefill=true --use-ccm=true --use-java-context=true --user-name=USERNAME --wrap-xa-resource=true --xa-datasource-properties=URL=jdbc:oracle:thin
```

I don't understand why the preferred method of cli syntax was not working but using this method it will be configurable.

If somebody knows a way to make it work in the other syntax I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

On Wildfly 10 this works:

`/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=TestDataSource/:add(driver-name=XA-Oracle,jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/testDS,background-validation=false,enlistment-trace=false,flush-strategy=FailingConnectionOnly,max-pool-size=20,min-pool-size=10,no-recovery=false,password=TEST,pool-prefill=true,query-timeout=10,same-rm-override=false,statistics-enabled=true,track-statements=NOWARN,url-property=jdbc:oracle:thin:@TEST:orcl,user-name=USERNAME,validate-on-match=false,enabled=true,allow-multiple-users=false,xa-datasource-class=oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource)`

Note the last property, which is required otherwise testing the connection may fail.

Also, there was apparently a bug in Wildfly 13, where it fails to interpret the `@` symbol and reports an error that

> at least one or more xa-datasource-property is required.

A fix was supposed to be put into Wildfly 14. However, I am seeing that the problem persists.

Comment: Not working on wildfly 20: WFLYJCA0069: At least one xa-datasource-property is required for an xa-datasource.
Nico's answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

Even WildFly 18 have this problem. I used a sample command like this below..
To do the `xa-datasource` creation with `xa-datasource-properties`

```
xa-data-source add --jndi-name=java:/jdbc/TesteOracle --name=TesteOracle --driver-name=oracle --password=usuario --user-name=senha  
--xa-datasource-properties=URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:HE
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the datasource MUST be disabled at creation time ..
it work for me as

```
xa-data-source add \
    --name=talentia-xxxxx\
    --driver-name=sqlserver \
    --jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/xxxxx \
    --user-name=xxxxx \
    --password=xxxx \
    --min-pool-size=10 \
    --max-pool-size=20 \
    --enabled=false \
    --use-java-context=true
    
/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxxxxx/xa-datasource-properties=URL:add( \
    value=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxxx \
)

/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxxxxxx:write-attribute( \
    name=valid-connection-checker-class-name, \
    value=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker \
)

/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxxxx:write-attribute( \
    name=background-validation, \
    value=true \
)

/subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=xxxxx:write-attribute( \
    name=same-rm-override, \
    value=true \
)

xa-data-source enable --name = xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done interactively via CLI by declaring all properties with data source in a batch for example:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] batch
[standalone@localhost:9990 / #] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MariaDBXADS:add(driver-name=mariadb-xa, jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/MariaDBXADS, user-name=jdv_user, password=jdv_pass, use-java-context=true)
[standalone@localhost:9990 / #] /subsystem=datasources/xa-data-source=MariaDBXADS/xa-datasource-properties=test:add(value=test-value)
[standalone@localhost:9990 / #] run-batch
The batch executed successfully
```